# Result of glucose with acetic anhydride and pyridine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the result when glucose is mixed with excess acetic anhydride and excess pyridine?

Comment: Related: [What are the roles of pyridine and DCM in the acylation of an alcohol?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44902/16683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it forms glucose pentaacetate. The acetic anhydride esterifies with all the alcohol groups on the glucose ring.

[image]